# Taylor series of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n^2 x)}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion

I have the following problem. I must show that the following function $f$ is infinitely differentiable, then find its Taylor series centered at $0$, and the corresponding radius of convergence:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n^2 x)}{2^n}.$$

I think that, since the series is absolutely convergent, it follows that it is infinitely differentiable, but I am not sure about that. Furthermore, I have no clue as to how to find the Taylor series. I was thinking maybe I could use the series expansion of the cosine, but I am not sure about that either.

Comment: Try finding $f^{(n)}(0)$ using the series expansion and seeing if it simplifies?

Answer (score 2):

This expression of $f$ can be differentiated with respect to $x$ straightforwardly, such that its even derivatives are given by
$$
f^{(2k)}(x) = (-1)^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{4k}}{2^n} \cos(n^2x),
$$
while the odd derivatives take the form
$$
f^{(2k+1)}(x) = (-1)^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{4k+2}}{2^n} \sin(n^2x),
$$
so that they will vanish at $x = 0$. In consequence, one has :
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty f^{(k)}(0) \frac{x^k}{k!} 
     = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^{2k}, 
\;\mathrm{with}\; 
a_k = \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{4k}}{2^n}.
$$
But I'm afraid no further simplications can be carried without referring to special functions in order to compute the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{4k}}{2^n}$. In addition, it is to be noticed that the final expression could have been achieved by replacing the cosine by its own Taylor expansion, as you intended to do.